# Sublimetext: how to make output into console?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

How to make output into console in Sublimetext? I would like to make some type of debugging into Sublimetext console while controller works, so is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

While not possible, you do have a few options for console logging with PHP.

First, there is a newer version of [FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firephp/), which is an extension for Firefox. When setup and used correctly, it sends debugging data to the Firefox console. The problem here is that Firefox's security doesn't allow for it to be installed unless you download it directly. See the notes in the "About this extension" section of the page I linked to. I use FirePHP a lot, but I use it with an old version of Firefox, because the old version of Firefox is better.

Second, you can use ChromePHP, which is like FirePHP for Chrome. It is a Chrome extension that you install. I don't really like it as much as FirePHP, but if you're a Chrome user, then it's probably better for you. A tutorial to get you started: [Use ChromePHP to debug PHP](https://coderwall.com/p/nwzxdg/use-chromephp-to-debug-php)

Last, and probably your best option, is to use [Symfony's VarDumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html). There is an option to use the ServerDumper dumper, and log to file. I use this in combination with BrowserSync. It's actually faster to just log to console. By the way, I'm not sure if this works on Windows.

Dumping to file looks something like this:

```
$dumpLog = ABSPATH . 'dumpLog.txt';
file_put_contents($dumpLog, '');

VarDumper::setHandler(function ($var) use ($dumpLog) {
    $cloner = new VarCloner();
    $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI 
        ? new CliDumper() 
        : new HtmlDumper();
    $dumper->setDisplayOptions([
        'maxDepth' => 12
    ]);

    $output = '';

    $dumper->dump(
        $cloner->cloneVar($var), 
        function ($line, $depth) use (&$output) {
            if ($depth >= 0) {
                $output .= str_repeat('  ', $depth).$line."\n";
            }
        }
    );
    file_put_contents($dumpLog, $output, FILE_APPEND);
});
```

Dumping to server like this:

```
VarDumper::setHandler(function ($var) {
    $cloner = new VarCloner();
    $dumper = new ServerDumper('tcp://127.0.0.1:9912');     
    $dumper->dump($cloner->cloneVar($var));
});
```

You're still going to need to learn how to use one of these debugging tools, but hopefully this helps you. I consider these essential for my job.